# Spring Cloud Contract - no bean named 'verifications' available

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I have a spring boot app running spring cloud contract

messageTest.groovy

```
Contract.make {
    label 'some_label'
    input {
        triggeredBy('messageTriggered()')
    }
    outputMessage {
        sentTo 'verifications'
        body 'foo'
        headers {
            messagingContentType(applicationJson())
        }
    }
}
```

My tests fail, when i look at the generated tests in the build folder,

```
ContractVerifierMessage response = contractVerifierMessaging.receive("verifications");
```

This line above keeps throwing the exception of

```
No bean named 'verifications' available
```

What am i doing wrong?

It looks like its injecting `SpringIntegrationStubMessages` and not `StreamStubMessages`...

Im using Spring Boot 1.5.8 with spring cloud starter kafka

```
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have both spring integration and stream on the classpath, and for some reason stream is not picked up, then try setting `stubrunner.integration.enabled` to `false`. That way only Stream should be picked.

Comment: where should this be set? Why would i have both spring integration and stream on the classpath? :/

Comment: Could you please upload the sample. Cause you anyways have integration and stream together. For some reason you have some misconfiguration

Comment: what part of the sample would you like to see?

Comment: The whole part. A sample that replicates the problem

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak please find the sample here https://github.com/winster/contract-test-sample Readme has instructions to replicate the issue. stubrunner.integration.enabled=false in test/resources/application.properties didnt help

Comment: okay. stubrunner.stream.enabled=false worked for me

Comment: Ok so it seems that you had stream on the classpath and didn't want stream to be used...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need the MessageVerifier bean to be instance of the StreamStubMessages class. It's a conditional one and its instantiation depends on the content of the class path. You may try to troubleshoot the issue by instantiating it explicitly:

```
@Bean
MessageVerifier<Message<?>> activeMqContractVerifier(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    return new StreamStubMessages(applicationContext);
}
```

It should end up with a no class def found exception that will guide you towards missing dependencies.

I had similar problem, but in my case there was ActiveMQ in place of Kafka (without spring integration or spring streams). As a consequence none of the available MessageVerifier seems to be suitable. For me the following minimalistic implementation (it's not a generic solution for ActiveMQ) of MessageVerifier did the job:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.MessageVerifier;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ActiveMqStubMessages implements MessageVerifier<Message<?>> {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public ActiveMqStubMessages(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void send(Message message, String destination) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> void send(T payload, Map<String, Object> headers, String destination) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> receive(String destination, long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = applicationContext.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);
        final long originalReceiveTimeout = jmsTemplate.getReceiveTimeout();
        try {
            jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(timeout, timeUnit));
            return (Message) new MessagingMessageConverter().fromMessage(jmsTemplate.receive(destination));
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(originalReceiveTimeout);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> receive(String destination) {
        return receive(destination, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```